# How to clone a smaller SSD to larger SSD on Ubuntu Linux 18.04?

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu, clone

This is my first time trying to the below task. So far I followed the links below

1. [Fastest way to migrate to a bigger SSD (18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105560/fastest-way-to-migrate-to-a-bigger-ssd-18-04)
2. [How would I speed up a full disk dd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523037/how-would-i-speed-up-a-full-disk-dd)
3. https://www.tigraine.at/2014/01/04/how-to-upgrade-to-an-ssd-with-minimal-effort

Description:
I'm currently running Ubuntu Linux installed on a 240 GB SSD and planning to upgrade it with a 500 GB SSD as is. Once everything is cloned (including partitions) I plan to swap the smaller SSD with the larger SSD in the laptop and move on.

Steps followed so far:

1. I've created a bootable USB flash drive for linux (Pass).
2. Booted the laptop using the flash drive (Pass)
3. Connected the new 500 GB SSD with laptop using the external
   SATA-III to USB 3.0 cable (Pass)
4. Successfully formatted the new SSD using the Disks GUI (Pass).
   [Screenshot inserted below for Disk formatted successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAY9M.png)
5. Successfully executed the dd command to copy/clone the content of main partition from older SSD to newer SSD (Pass) [dd completed successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fczwq.png)
6. After copy I execute the "sudo lshw -C disk" I see original 240 GB SSD and the Flash drive details but not the newer SSD [Output of lshw
   command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZOBz.png)
7. No clue about how to bring in the remaining partitions from the 240 GB SSD onto the newer SSD [Other partitions on old SSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPVbH.png)

**Problem statement**: Once I swap the SSDs I wish to have similar partitions on the newer SSD. As of now I'm clueless of how to carve out the remaining two partitions on the newer SSD.

If possible, please let me know:

```
If I can start using the newer SSD in existing condition without any partitions?
If I need to execute any more steps that I'm missing here.
```

Thanks in advance,
Bhaskar

Comment: Using dd is a bit for bit copy. So any partitioning in advance is removed. And dd is really for same size to same size drive copy. If gpt, you have a backup gpt partition table that is supposed to be at end of drive, in the middle. With dd and gpt you have to copy drive as each partition has GUID which must match partition table & backup partition table. Normally better to just do a new install and restore your data from your backups. You also cannot reboot a clone with both drives connected, you have duplicate UUIDS which creates a conflict.

Comment: @oldfred The duplicate UUIDs are a problem in both `grub` and `/etc/fstab` I wrote a script to clone Ubuntu to another partition (or disk) which avoids these pitfalls of Clonzilla and dd: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-backkup-clone-ubuntu-to-another-partition/1028605#1028605